How to Configure GAM Remote Authentication for Multiple Deployment Units in GeneXus 18
I have a GeneXus 18 upgrade 8 Knowledge Base with GAM, generating .NET Core.
It has 2 Deployment Units: one for installing the customer-facing web frontend and another for the back office, which is also web-based. The deployment will be to two docker containers with different URL addresses, but they will share the same ApplicationID, Repository, and Identity Provider, with Single Sign-On enabled.
I understand that in this scenario, I will need to use the GAM Remote Authentication Type.
Do I need to define an Authentication Type for each Deployment Unit / Container?
I am asking because the GAM Remote Authentication Type only allows one Local Site URL, which must match one of the callback URLs defined in the application.
